# Use SED to replace part of a current variable with user input variable

Tags: bash, sed, variable, string

I'm trying to replace only part of the existing variable with a new user input variable as below:

```
#Current Variable:
gdbName=Test.MY.DOMAIN.COM <--I need to replace the "Test" (This can be any other string not just Test e.g. CDB79 etc.) part only in this variable with new user input variable. 

#New user input variable:
read -p "Enter CDB Name : "  CDBName

#I tried the following line:
sed -i "s/gdbName=*.MY.DOMAIN.COM/gdbName=$CDBName/" somefile.txt
```

but it replaces the whole variable.

Any suggestions?

Note: I am updating the variable in a file.

Comment: Did you mean to use `gdbName=*.MY.DOMAIN.COM`? That means match `gdbName`, then 0 or more `=` and then any character, followed by `MY.DOMAIN.COM`. Maybe you wanted `.*` instead? What is this `dbca.rsp` file? Is that where the replacement should occur? So it isn't actually a variable but a file?

Comment: Are you trying to change the contents of a shell variable named `gdbName` that exists in your environment, or trying to change the contents of a file that contains the line `gdbName=Test.MY.DOMAIN.COM`? Please [edit] your question to clarify. and provide concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: Could `$CDBName` ever contain a `&` or `\1` or `/` or newline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to modify a file wherein you have some line,

```
gdbName=Test.MY.DOMAIN.COM
```

Then this could be done using

```bash
sed "s/^\(gdbName\)=Test\./\1=$CDBName./" somefile
```

or, if you need to be more generic and not specify the `Test` string, you could match any string not containing a dot (including the empty string):

```bash
sed "s/^\(gdbName\)=[^.]*\./\1=$CDBName./" somefile
```

These commands replaces the start of the line, up to the first dot, with the variable name (the string `gdbName`), an equal sign, and the value of the shell variable `CDBName`.

It is assumed that the user input in `CDBName` does not contain `&`, `/`, or any backslash-encoded character sequences special to `sed`.

In either case, a shell script does not need to define any variable called `gdbName`.

Your attempt removes the trailing part of the domain name because you are explicitly asking `sed` to match and replace it.

Answer (score 0):

To set the new name dynamically, by a variable, for instance (here only shown for the permanent change):

Close to your attempt:

> sed -i "s/gdbName=*.MY.DOMAIN.COM/gdbName=$CDBName/" somefile.txt

```
sed -i "s/gdbName=.*\.MY\.DOMAIN\.COM/gdbName=$CDBName.MY.DOMAIN.COM/" somefile.txt
```

Note that dots in regular expressions match any character, but including the dot itself, so masking the dot here is a bit over the top, for most cases.